# How to access different parameter from field.Method in Python

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I would like to change my postal code to  `''` if its `None` but cannot access the country_code parameter properly to do it. What am I doing wrong?

```
class AddressSchema(Schema):
        
    def _postal_check(self, postal):
        allowed_countries = ["GE","BT","HK","MO"]
        postal_code = postal.postalCode
        country_code = postal.countryCode
        if postal_code is None and country_code in allowed_countries:
            postal_code = ''
        return postal_code

    countryCode = fields.Str(validate=Length(equal=2), required=True)
    postalCode = fields.Method(serialize='_postal_check', allow_none=True, required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code: the variable you pass as a parameter to your function is not the one used, then the variable `allowed_countries` is not correctly declared.

In addition, you use two different variables: the declared variable `countryCode` uses the `CamelCase` style while the variable you call uses the `lower_case_with_underscores style`: `country_code`. You must harmonize the names of your variables:

```
class AddressSchema(Schema):
        
    def _postal_check(self, postal):
        allowed_countries = ["GE","BT","HK","MO"]
        if postal is None and self.country_code in allowed_countries:
            self.postal_code = ''
        return self.postal_code

    country_code = fields.Str(validate=Length(equal=2), required=True)
    postal_code = fields.Method(serialize='_postal_check', allow_none=True, required=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, You helped me find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to access postal as an object and not as a dictionary so the solution is

```
class AddressSchema(Schema):
    def _postal_check(self, postal):
        allowed_countries = ["GE","BT","HK","MO"]
        postal_code = postal['postalCode']
        country_code = postal['countryCode']
        if postal_code is None and country_code in allowed_countries:
            postal_code = ''
        return postal_code

 country_code = fields.Str(validate=Length(equal=2), required=True)
 postal_code = fields.Method(serialize='_postal_check', allow_none=True, required=True)
```